# Html boxes moving when browser resized

Tags: css, static, position

when i resize the browser, three elements in the middle (It's for everybody, It's one big community, its fun) position dont stay static. the third box goes under the other two boxes.

Here is the link,http://www.archimedus.com/archimedus/

I have been battling with this css issue for a day now.

It could be very simple but still i haven't been able to figure out what mistake i have made.

can someone please advise.

Comment: What do you think *should* happen if the viewport isn't wide enough for all 3 elements?

Comment: there should be a horizontal scroll i guess, is that right ?

Comment: @Vinod - there's no right or wrong, but the big thing nowadays is responsive web design.  Typically your elements should adjust gracefully as the viewport changes size

Comment: but i am not sure how to do that. i have tried all the positioning elements but still unable to get that right.

Comment: @Vinod Ok, well what do you *want* to happen?  Do you *want* it to scroll horizontally?  Users typically do not like that, but your large header image already restricts how narrow the viewport can go before horizontal scrolling creeps in.

Comment: but in the case of the browser being resized and the viewport is reduced then the elements that hid should be visible after horizontally scrolling right i suppose?

Comment: Yes, the elements will be visible when the user scrolls.  The question still remains:  do you want the horizontal scrolling to be there on narrower viewports, even though users typically do not like it?

Comment: what other options do i have?

Comment: This would be a simple way of laying out the elements in a responsive way:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mpfye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this would be to give the boxes a max width of 33%.

```
#content_mass_bottom #bottom_text {
   float: left;
   width: 425px;
   max-width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for that tip. That actually helped me.:)

Comment: @Vinod your welcome. Can if this is the right answer for you, can you mark it as such? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking your html marckup. You must use **bottom_text** classes instead of id's . You should not have duplicated id's in the document.

Then you must take a decision about what do **you** want to happen width your divs

**Specific to your question**

If the target is to avoid the relocation effect, wrap then in a **container div** and let them float inside of it. Then set a minimum width to your wraper div. Decide how will behave the overflow of it.

Your floting divs can use relative margins in order to obtain some flexible layout, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `bottom_text` divs into the `tbox1/2/3` divs.

```
   <div id="tbox1">
        <img src="/archimedus/images/everybody.png" class="everybody">      
        <div id="bottom_text">
            <p class="bottom_text">Many hands make light work. Imagine what we can achieve with our collective abilities With Archimedus there is an unlimited amount of knowledge available, waiting to be tapped by you. You’ll never be bored again. Best of all… it’s free!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```